# No formats supported in PHP/ImageMagik/imagick

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, freebsd, imagick

I've installed pecl-imagick from FreeBSD ports and it can't do a thing with images.

phpinfo() reports this:

```
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    0
ImageMagick supported formats:  no value
```

But ImageMagick installed correctly and show all it's stuff:

```
$ convert -list configure
...
DELEGATES     bzlib fftw fontconfig jpeg jng lzma png zlib
...
```

What could be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found that having an extension for **GraphicsMagick** (a "better" fork) installed causes that.

If you don't feel how it makes any sense, I'm totally with you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install PHP from ports? Update your ports and re-install packages.