# Enabling Gmagick PHP module causes ImageMagick (Imagick) module to report 0 supported formats

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to get both imagick and gmagick extensions enabled on the same machine (ubuntu 12.04 - though same problem in older versions).

I have a working ImageMagick/Imagick installation - with 206 supported formats...up until the moment I enable the gmagick module - then it reports that 0 are supported. I was able to isolate the problem thanks to this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350707/543871.  With gmagick enabled, graphicsmagick works perfectly well, just at the expense of imagemagick. Any ideas? Here is the output from phpinfo before and after enabling gmagick:

**BEFORE** (just imagick installed):

```
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.0.1
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-04-30 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2012-04-30
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    206
ImageMagick supported formats   3FR, A, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BGRA, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, C, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, J2C, JNG, JP2, JPC, JPEG, JPG, JPX, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

**AFTER** (imagick + gmagick both enabled):

```
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.0.1
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-04-30 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2012-04-30
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    0
ImageMagick supported formats   no value
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a PHP maintainer, "Imagick and Gmagick cannot really co-exist together on the same environment as some of the symbols are similar." (See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59285.)